# Ссылку на сайт и чтоб переходило

Tags: android

Необходимо разместить, например, в MainActivity ссылку на сайт, при нажатии на которую мы перешли бы сайт.

Answer (score 1):

label на label вешаем onclick.

в onclick:

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

Comment: круто! работает!

Answer (score 0):

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href=\"http://google.com\">link</a>"));
```

*UPD:*

Забыл упомянуть, что для `TextView` так же нужно назначить `MovementMethod`:

```
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Comment: почему то не работает в эмуляторе по крайней мере

Comment: Дополнил ответ.